# Show only childs and grandchilds of certain post in admin

Tags: wp-admin

How can I filter out post lists in WP's admin so that only child and grandchild posts are visible?

So that a list like

- Item 1

  - Item 1.1
  - - Item 1.1.1
  - - Item 1.1.2
  - Item 1.2
  - - Item 1.2.1
  - - Item 1.2.1
  - - Item 1.2.3
  - Item 1.3

Would become

- Item 1.1

  - - Item 1.1.1
  - - Item 1.1.2
- Item 1.2
- - Item 1.2.1
  - - Item 1.2.1
  - - Item 1.2.3
  - Item 1.3

I've tried using the parse_query -filter in the admin side but I can only get the children without the grand childs, or the grandchilds but under the wrong child.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code and arguments you are using in parse_query filter, I can be certain, but if think the `post_parent__not_in` query argument achieves what you want.

```
function wpse_282340_exclude_posts_from_admin($query)
{
    // bail early if we are not in the admin side
    if (!is_admin()) {
        return $query;
    }

    global $pagenow, $post_type;

    // check if we are in the edit screen for page post type
    if ($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'page') {
        // filter out the pages with post_parent = 0 (ie. no post_parent, first level pages)
        $query->query_vars['post_parent__not_in'] = array(0);
    }

    return $query;

}
add_filter('parse_query', 'wpse_282340_exclude_posts_from_admin');
```

Let me know if works for you.